# Convert from type alias to original type

Tags: go

Suppose I have a type alias like this:

```
type myint int;
```

Now I have a `myint` type called `foo`. Is there any way to convert foo from a `myint` to an `int`?

Comment: Please read the [specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec). It should clear up a couple of things.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a `myint` to an `int`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myint int

func main() {
    foo := myint(1) // foo has type myint
    i := int(foo)   // use type conversion to convert myint to int
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

The type `myint` is a not an alias for int. It's a different type. For example, the expression `myint(0) + int(1)` does not compile because the operands are different types. There are two built-in type aliases in Go, rune and byte. Applications cannot define their own aliases.

Comment: +1 for the type semantics in Go! One of Scala's weaknesses is that `type` makes aliases not types, counter-intuitively perhaps. Go got this right IMHO.

Comment: Since this answer is quite old: Starting from go 1.9 and onwards one can indeed define true type aliases: `type myint = int` (note the '=' sign). However this feature is meant to be used only for use-cases such as refactoring, not as a replacement of type definitions.